# Why do we dip noble metals (Ir, Pd) into NaOH for an oxide coating in thermal oxidation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal, organic-oxidation

I've noticed that a common technique for creating a layer of oxide onto palladium or iridium is to dip it into high concentrated NaOH prior to putting it in a furnace for ~800C.

I've been reading numerous papers and it leads me to a textbook that I can't find accessible: Kauko, Y. and Knappsberg, L. (1939) Z. Elektrochem. 45, 760

The papers that I've been reading are 
W. T. Grubb and L. H. King, Analytical Chemistry 1980 52 (2), 270-273 
DOI: 10.1021/ac50052a013

and

https://doi.org/10.1016/0005-2795(76)90263-4

if anyone can help me solve this problem, I would be eternally grateful!